# What is the visual studio test host?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-sdk

`vstesthost.exe`. What is it? How do I install it?

I know it has to do with `MSBuild` and the *Visual Studio SDK(both installed)*.

Google searches are also yielding bupkis.

Comment: Please describe what you have tried and post possible errors. The question is very broad.

Comment: Yes, and rightly so. It is something that was brewing it out a pre release from Microsoft that perhaps they have not even worked out how it is supposed to work. If anyone tries to download source and run tests they will have this same issue. Might want to reconsider your -1. I also answered the question, so I think you were perhaps a little too trigger happy.

Comment: If the comment was targeted at me, I didn't downvote your question. Also you did answer it after I commented on it.

Questions from new users are monitored by the community and will get commented and voted on like this. This is the very nature of SO.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs into this I hope this helps.

The whole problem arose when I was trying to get the tests to run going for the nodejs tools plugin on github. This uses Visual Studio automation hence the requirement for the missing vstesthost. Which is in fact a dll not an executable.

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools

Much of the infrastructure to get it all going is is still very much in the process of being documented.  I thought this was something well known and perhaps that I was missing something obvious.

I had to install an msi from the following location.

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/tree/master/Common/Prerequisites